# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name (…) Failed to introspect Class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, wildfly

I am trying to deploy a Spring Boot application on a WildFly server.

My application is composed of 3 sub projects : dao (jar), metier (jar) and web (war).
Web depends on metier, and metier depend on dao.

Using Java, Spring Boot 2, Maven, Angular 6, I adapted my application (pom.xml files) to be deployed on my WildFly server.

Before adaptation for my WildFly server, my application works fine on local (Eclipse Tomcat and Angular local server).

First, I tried to do from the terminal maven clean install on my web project (war) by command :

```
mvn clean install --also-make
```

But dependencies with metier and dao did'nt satisfy.

So I created a parent pom.xml for my parent project.

This is my parent pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-projet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>ecommerce-dao</module>
    <module>ecommerce-metier</module>
    <module>ecommerce-web</module>
</modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And this is the pom.xml files for my 3 sub projects :

ecommerce-dao :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <!--   <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId> -->
    <artifactId>ecommerce-dao</artifactId>
 <!--   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ecommerce-dao</name>
    <description>e-commerce Hillsoft DAO</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecommerce-projet</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

<!--    <parent> -->
<!--        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version> -->
<!--        <relativePath/> lookup parent from repository -->
<!--    </parent> -->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<!--    <build> -->
<!--        <plugins> -->
<!--            <plugin> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--            </plugin> -->
<!--        </plugins> -->
<!--    </build> -->

</project>
```

ecommerce-metier :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!--    <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId> -->
    <artifactId>ecommerce-metier</artifactId>
<!--    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ecommerce-metier</name>
    <description>e-commerce Hillsoft Métier</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecommerce-projet</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <!--    <parent> -->
    <!--        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
    <!--        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> -->
    <!--        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version> -->
    <!--        <relativePath/> lookup parent from repository -->
    <!--    </parent> -->

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecommerce-dao</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<!--    <build> -->
<!--        <plugins> -->
<!--            <plugin> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--            </plugin> -->
<!--        </plugins> -->
<!--    </build> -->

</project>
```

ecommerce-web :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<!--    <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId> -->
    <artifactId>ecommerce-web</artifactId>
<!--    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ecommerce-web</name>
    <description>e-commerce Hillsoft Web</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-projet</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<!--    <parent> -->
<!--        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version> -->
<!--        <relativePath/> lookup parent from repository -->
<!--    </parent> -->

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.hillsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecommerce-metier</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.wildfly.core/wildfly-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-server</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

<!--    <build> -->
<!--        <plugins> -->
<!--            <plugin> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--            </plugin> -->
<!--        </plugins> -->
<!--    </build> -->

</project>
```

But the problem persists. This error is happening when I'm trying to maven clean install my parent project from the terminal :

```
package does not exist [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Consultat Hillsoft/workingset/workspace-ecommerce/ecommerce-projet/ecommerce-metier/src/main/java/fr/hillsoft/metier/impl/InternauteImpl.java:[11,25] package fr.hillsoft.model does not exist

[INFO] 100 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] ecommerce-projet 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [  1.986 s]
[INFO] ecommerce-dao ...................................... SUCCESS [ 18.025 s]
[INFO] ecommerce-metier ................................... FAILURE [  1.687 s]
[INFO] ecommerce-web 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.369 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-31T14:17:18+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project ecommerce-metier: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ecommerce-metier
```

In search of a solution, as I'm using Eclipse, I tried "Maven build…" from "Run As" entry on web sub project, with Goals "clean install", and "Skip Tests" and "Resolve Workspace artifacts" checked.

I copied WAR file created from target repository into wildfly standalone deployments repository.

This error is happening when I'm trying to deploy my project on the WildFly server with standalone.sh run :

This is essential lines of error listing :

```
11:51:35,702 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Application run failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/hillsoft/model/MyUser

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.hillsoft.model.MyUser from [Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

11:51:35,704 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/hillsoft/model/MyUser

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.hillsoft.model.MyUser from [Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

11:51:35,710 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\": java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/hillsoft/model/MyUser
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.hillsoft.model.MyUser from [Module \"deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\""],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
11:51:35,769 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
11:51:35,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT": java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountRestController': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.hillsoft.controller.AccountRestController] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

11:51:35,883 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started (with errors) in 11384ms - Started 516 of 768 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 405 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:51:35,907 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2
11:51:35,960 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in 59ms

WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/ecommerce-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

This is first lines of MyUser.java :

```
package fr.hillsoft.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Version;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter;

@Entity
public class MyUser {
    private Long id;
```

And this is first lines of AccountRestController.java :

```
package fr.hillsoft.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import fr.hillsoft.metier.AccountService;
import fr.hillsoft.model.MyUser;

@RestController
public class AccountRestController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public MyUser register(@RequestBody RegisterForm registerForm) {
```

All attemps are probably due to same cause, is it due to Maven dependencies ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried to add ecommerce-dao, ecommerce-metier and ecommerce-web as dependencies in your parent pom? using <version>${project.version}</version> for each one as version number(since is hinerited)

Comment: Thank you Rick for your answer. Should I try to add dependencies before or after <modules> block ?

Comment: After with a dependencies block

Comment: You are using a Spring Boot application as a dependency in another Spring Boot application. That isn't going to work. Only your `web` project should be a spring boot project not the other ones. They are Spring Boot projects because you globally defined the spring boot plugin in the parent pom of all your projects. Remove that and only add it to your web project.

Comment: Hello Rick, the mvn clean install fails : each of ecommerce-dao, ecommerce-metier and ecommerce- web "is referencing itself". I'm looking for exclude recursivity option of mvn clean install.

Comment: Thank you M. Deinum for your answer. My 3 sub-projects are Spring Boot projects. I think I can keep Spring Boot dependency with inheritance. I keep your advise in mind.

Comment: Rick, with "mvn clean install --non-recursive" command, it fails with message : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ecommerce-projet: Could not resolve dependencies for project fr.hillsoft:ecommerce-projet:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact fr.hillsoft:ecommerce-metier:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

(ecommerce-dao was previously installed individually.)